# How can I have borders around the table row, but not on any inner-cells?

Tags: html, css-tables

I would like a table such that I have multiple rows, but no inner-vertical lines. That implies a complete border around the table, but no inner-column borders. Specifically, I would want the ability to have that, but with spacing around each row and curved edges, as shown in this example code: https://jsfiddle.net/n14ye7nk/

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#table {
  border-spacing: 0.3em;
}

#table td {
  border: 2px solid #30c;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately tables aren't really designed to do what you are asking.

In order to have the border around the row rather than the cell, simply shift the `border` rule to the `#table tr` selector, and also add `border-collapse: collapse` to the `<table>` element itself.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0.3em;
}

#table tr {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#table td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>this</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>a table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>with</td>
      <td>rounded</td>
      <td>cells</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Table row spacing can be done with `border-collapse: separate`... though this doesn't allow for the border.

Note that neither approach will allow `border-radius` to be applied to `tr`. The best way of doing this is to simply set **individual** corner radii on the `<td>` element `:first-child` and `:last-child`. Note that you'll want `cellspacing="0"` on the `<table>` itself.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#table td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

#table tr:first-of-type td {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

#table tr:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

#table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>this</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>a table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>with</td>
      <td>rounded</td>
      <td>cells</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Again, this is not ideal.

The best way of handling this really is by completing replacing the table with `<div>` elements instead. This way you can make use of `calc()` in the `width` to ensure even spacing, `float: left` to control how many elements are in a row, and `margin-bottom` to add whitespace in between the rows. You also only have to apply the core `border-radius` on the `.row` itself:

```css
.row {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - (3px + 2em));

}

.row:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>this</div>
  <div>is</div>
  <div>a table</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>with</div>
  <div>rounded</div>
  <div>cells</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Incredible! Wonderful explanation. Thank you so much!